# Regex to trim leading/trailng commas: ,aa,bb,cc,

Tags: regex, trim

I'm trying to capture `aa,bb,cc` from the following strings:

```
,aa,bb,cc,
aa,bb,cc,
,aa,bb,cc
aa,bb,cc
```

My plan was to:

1. Match the start of line anchor, or the anchor followed by a comma
2. Capture until the end of line anchor, or a comma followed by the end of line anchor

The closest I've got is: `(?:^,|^)(.*)(?:$|,$)`, but that includes trailing commas in the capture group:

```
,aa,bb,cc, -> aa,bb,cc,
aa,bb,cc,  -> aa,bb,cc,
,aa,bb,cc  -> aa,bb,cc
aa,bb,cc   -> aa,bb,cc
```

Why isn't it working, and what's the right solution?

Comment: You can probably do this with your language's `trim()` method (or equivalent). Certainly jQuery and PHP can take a parameter of characters to trim from the string (eg `$str = trim($str, ',')`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
^,*(?<trimmed>.*?),*$
```

Comment: Thanks, that got it. For anyone else reading, the `?<trimmed>` is apparently [.NET's version of named-group syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html).

Comment: Heh, if I had recognized the named-group syntax, I would have realized my later answer was exactly the same as this. :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:
`^,*(.*?),*$`

The key idea is the lazy star `*?` because I want trailing commas (and even multiple trailing commas, I'm assuming) to be matched by the last `,*` instead of being matched inside the parentheses.

Comment: However, I generally wouldn't use RegEx for this.  As Joe mentioned, most languages have some kind of `trim` function already.  Notably not JavaScript, unless you're using a framework that has it.