# Regex to trim off leading and trailing slashes and catch the rest

Tags: regex, url

I am trying to catch URL paths to yield the portion without leading and ending slashes `/`. Empty input characters before or after the trimming should be matched. The desired regex will behave as follows:

```
input-string        captured-string
-----------------------------------
/a/b/c/             a/b/c               
/a/b/c              a/b/c               
/                   (empty)
(empty)             (empty)
```

I use `echo /a/b/c/d | sed -nr 's=(/(.+?)/)?=\2=p'`  and its flavors as the test tools as suggested by [gurus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494793/extracting-tail-from-a-string-using-pcre) and notice that the following regular expressions fail to do the job:

```
regex           input-string    wrong capture
---------------------------------------------
(/(.+?)/)?      /a/b/c          a/bc
(/(.+?)/)       /a/b/c          a/bc
(/(.+?)/)       /a              (doesn't match)
(/(.+?)/?)      /a/b/c/         a/b/c/
(/([^/]+)/?)    /a/b/c          ab/c
(/([^/.+])/?)   /a/b/c          ab/c
/*(.*?)/*       /a/b/c/         a/b/c/
```

[The alleged correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252960/regex-to-trim-leading-trailng-commas-aa-bb-cc) appears to not be working, either:

```
echo /a/b/c | sed -nr 's=/*(?<x>.*?)/*=\k<x>=p'
```

because it gives this error message:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

Helps will be much appreciated.

Edit: As pointed out by `CompuChip`, I used wrong test tool `sed` which appears to be not supporting non-greedy modifiers. The actual regex engine I am using is `boost::regex_match()` which gives me correct results given regex such as `/?(.*?)/?`. So I would like to close this question.

Comment: How about `^/?(.*)/?$` - i.e. matching the beginning and end of the string explicitly.

Comment: `echo /a/b/c/ | sed -r 's:^/?(.*)/?$:\1:g'` gives `/a/b/c/`. Maybe it is the greedy `.*` that retains the trailing `/`.

Comment: I think the problem is that the echo includes a space. At least on my Windows system with GNU tools, `echo /a/b/c/ | sed -r s:^/?(.*)/?$:{\1}:g` returns `{a/b/c/ }`.

Comment: Strange! In Debian Wheezy I get `{a/b/c/}` with exactly the same input and regex as yours. If I save the only line `/a/b/c/` in file `input` and then `sed -r 's:^/?(.*)/?$:{\1}:g' input`, I get `{a/b/c/}`, too.

Comment: So I think the problem is related, as you say, to greedy matching. If the string ends in `/`, apparently `sed` prefers putting that inside the match and not matching on the final `/?$`. Unfortunately, it is not possible to disable greedy matching in `sed` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed) but since I read below that you are actually using boost, perhaps `^/?(.*?)/?$` will work (i.e. my original suggestion with a non-greedy `?` modifier added).

Comment: @CompuChip Thank you for the correct answer! Using incorrect test tool `sed` wasted myself one full day.

Answer (score 1):

Try following `sed`

```
sed -r 's:^/|/$::'
```

**Short Description**

Match : `^/|/$` = `^/` or `/$` i.e. leading and trailing slash

Replace : (empty) i.e. trim the match

**Test**

```
$ cat file
/a/b/c/
/a/b/c
/

$ sed -r 's:^/|/$::' file
a/b/c/
a/b/c
```

Comment: As more than one match is possible you need to add the `g` flag to cater for this condition.

Comment: @potong As per my understanding, `g` flag will do global match in a single line. Here `^/` or `/$` can happen only once in every line. Hence I don't see that requirement although adding `g` won't hurt. Please correct me if I missed something. Counter-example would be helpful

Comment: I should have mentioned that I must use group, capture, and back reference. In fact I am using boost `regex_match`.

Comment: @MasaoLiu Instead can't you use boost `regex_replace` and do above replacement? once it's done, all output strings are same as required capture only. Are you not trying to solve this difficult way when it's much easier other way round? Am I missing something? bdw you have wrongly tagged `sed` and even showed `sed` examples.

Comment: @jkshah Oops! I thought mentioning `boost regex_match` instead of the actual framework I am actually using, `cppCMS`, narrows down my issue. `cppcms::application::attach()` expects regular expression as parameter. Having received the URL from clients, the framework internally calls the related function according to the captured characters returned by `boost regex_match()` given the aforementioned regular expression. By the way, I have just removed tag `sed`.

Comment: @jkshah the title says `Regex to trim off leading and trailing slashes and catch the rest` and the first example `/a/b/c/`conveys this.

Comment: @potong I agree. My point here was, output of `sed` can be easily captured in array of string. Anyways if `sed` is not the right tool, I might be out of league.

Answer (score 0):

if only this kind of entry (so not inside other string)

```
sed "s#$#/#;s#^[^/].*##;s#/*$##;s#^/##"
```

Don't avoid thing like //bad/path/